# How to update Facebook status using C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to update my Facebook status using an ASP.NET website. Is it possible for this to be done in C#?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the .NET API:

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/